# How to print a string in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, printing

I do this to output the contents of a string (and nothing more):

```
fprintf( '%s', my_str );
```

but it feels like I've missed a function that takes only `my_str` as an argument. Which function should I use?

Comment: `disp` might be an alternative but it doesn't give you much control over the output. http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/disp.html

Comment: `disp` is what I was looking for! For some reason I only checked `display` which is different.

Answer (score 3):

`disp` is what you are looking for, as in:

```
>>disp string  %command format for single string arguments
string  
>>disp 'string test' 
string test
>>disp ('string test') %function format
string test
```

and for a variable

```
>> test= 'string';
>> disp(test)
string
```

but not

```
>>disp string test
Error using disp
Too many input arguments.
```

and you can always do this:

```
>> a = 'string';
>> a

a =

string
```

Answer (score 1):

Use DISP  - disp(my_str)

Type "help disp" on MATLAB command line.